# I need help to loop an action in my code

Tags: java, loops

i want to loop an action in may code, it shall be repeated for ever until the progrmm is closed:
I think that is't a very easy thing and so I'd be happy if you help me! :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException{

    final Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.delay(2000);



    //code to repeat
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(1);


}
```

}

Comment: looping is cake, you just need to define your loop exit event.  What are you actually wanting to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

#### This will loop forever

```
while(true)
{
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(1);
}
```

#### This will loop `n` number of times:

```
final int n = 1000;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(1);
}
```